# Macro not going to next WS

Tags: vba, excel, loops

For some reason my code is not going to the next worksheet, any help would be appreciated.

```
CleanUpMetricsBooks()

Dim ws As Worksheet

For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets

Range("M:N,P:Q,U:V,X:Y").EntireColumn.Delete

End

Next ws

End Sub
```

Comment: change `Range("M:N,P:Q,U:V,X:Y").EntireColumn.Delete` to `ws.Range("M:N,P:Q,U:V,X:Y").EntireColumn.Delete`  You need to qualify the line or it will only refer to the active sheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify which sheet you are "talking" about, here, just add `Ws.` before `Range(...`

Because if you don't specify which sheet you are working, **by default, Excel will consider the Active Sheet**!

```
Sub CleanUpMetricsBooks()
Dim ws As Worksheet

For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    ws.Range("M:N,P:Q,U:V,X:Y").EntireColumn.Delete
Next ws

End Sub
```

Comment: Was just about to post my comment as an answer.

Comment: Thank you! much appreciated.

Comment: @ScottCraner : But you still can, I just saw it and that you posted your comment before my answer. And even if there is multiple answers you can still get an upvote or as the OP didn't accept mine yet, you could have that too! ;)

Comment: @AsimAhmed : take a minute to take the tour to see how to use SO (accept answers and use votes) : http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: Na, man its okay.  I was vacillating on whether to post and as soon as I decided to you posted yours.  All's good.

Comment: @ScottCraner : Anyway, you've got rewarded! ;)

Comment: Thanks, but a majority will be rolled back later tonight, I think the max you can do that to is 4, but I appreciate the sentiment.

Comment: @ScottCraner : I took time to understand, but you are saying there is a "protection" against that kind of votes, guess that make sense!^^ Anyway, good luck with everything! ;)